# Unfefined status using a class field in Angular

Tags: angular, spring

The problem is concerned about display fields of class in html view or in console.
My config:

```
export class UserDataService {

  constructor(
    private http:HttpClient
  ) { }

  executeHelloUserBeanService(){
    return this.http.get<User>("http://localhost:8081/physio-node/test/admin");
  }
}
```

The object that is being passed on from Spring:

```
public class UserDTO {
    public String username;
    public String email;

    public UserDTO(User user) {
        this.username = user.getUserName();
        this.email = user.getUserE_mail();
    }
}
```

User model in Angular:

```
export class User {
 public username: string;
 public email: string;

 
    constructor(username: string, email: string){
      this.username = username;
      this.email = email;
    }
  }
```

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  name: string = "true";

  constructor(
    private service:UserDataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshProfile();
  }

   refreshProfile(){
    this.service.executeHelloUserBeanService().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.user = response;
        console.log(this.user);
        console.log(this.user.username);
      }
    )
  }
```

So,
console.log(this.user) seems correct because I can see the full object in the console
[image: Console]

but when i try to display {{user.username}} in html view it doesn't work and console in line: console.log(this.user.username) displays: undefined;

@edit

```
public class UserService {

    private UserTaskRepository userTaskRepository;

    public UserService(UserTaskRepository userTaskRepository) {
        this.userTaskRepository = userTaskRepository;
    }

    public UserDTO getUserbyID(String username){
        return userTaskRepository.findByUserName(username)
                .stream().
                        map(UserDTO::new).
                        collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
    }




}
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot with the console after it logs `this.user`? Maybe the response structure is different.

Comment: Screenshot added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from the server seems to be an array of users, not a single user as you expect. You can either correct that on the backend side, or extract the first element from the response data:

```
executeHelloUserBeanService(){
    return this.http.get<User[]>("http://localhost:8081/physio-node/test/admin").pipe(
      // make sure the array is there and it has at least 1 element
      filter(res => res && res.length > 0),
      // extract the first element
      map(res => res[0])
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is it a good practise to change getUserbyID method like me ?

Comment: Even though this is more like a java question rather than an angular related one, I would go for `findFirst` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst-- . `return userTaskRepository.findByUserName(username).stream().map(UserDTO::new).findFirst()` (instead of collecting the result into a list).

Answer (score 1):

In attached screenshot, It's clearing showing that the response is not single an `object` It's an `array` of `User Object`. So either you have to change the implementation of backend like return single `object` instead of `array` or change the implementation of this `refreshProfile()` method like this

```
refreshProfile(){
    this.service.executeHelloUserBeanService().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.user = response[0]; // just read first element from response
        console.log(this.user);
        console.log(this.user.username);
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Is it a good practise to change getUserbyID method like me ? (Method, added to post)

Comment: You are using Java Spring Boot for backend right? I am not too much aware of Spring boot, but I know spring boot already provide built-in method for getting single object so it will be a good if you follow the best practices